# Getting the mode of a character column after every hour elapsed in separate column?

Tags: r, string, date, mode

I have a very large dataset - around 20 million observations and this is its basic structure -

```
           date       time      string
  1     01/01/2020   20:00:00     A  
  2     01/01/2020   20:13:12     B
  3     01/01/2020   20:37:45     C
  4     01/01/2020   20:39:07     D 
  5     01/01/2020   20:41:29     A
  6     01/01/2020   20:46:48     E
  7     01/01/2020   21:00:00     J
```

I would like to have a new column, "mode" perhaps, that would calculate the most frequently occurring text string in the "string" column, but only on an hourly interval.  So the table would end up with something like this -

```
           date       time      string      mode
  1     01/01/2020   20:00:00     A          
  2     01/01/2020   20:13:12     B
  3     01/01/2020   20:37:45     C
  4     01/01/2020   20:39:07     D 
  5     01/01/2020   20:41:29     A
  6     01/01/2020   20:46:48     E
  7     01/01/2020   21:00:00     J          A
  8     01/01/2020   21:20:12     I
  9     01/01/2020   21:38:32     I  
  10    01/01/2020   21:43:12     A
  11    01/01/2020   21:49:50     I
  12    01/01/2020   21:54:50     B
  13    01/01/2020   22:00:00     A          I
  14    01/01/2020   22:03:45     B
```

so that every time the hour digit increments, a mode is taken of the string column, and then the mode measurement resets for the next hour-long interval.

I'm very new to R, so unfortunately I don't have any attempts or error messages to show.  I've looked at many other similar topics / threads and haven't come across anything that has helped me find a viable solution.  Certainly not asking for anyone to write code for me - just any suggestions at all would be very much appreciated.

Comment: My mistake - thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `library(data.table)` we can do

```
setDT(df1)[, hour := paste(date, sub(':.+','', time))]
df1[, n := seq(.N), by = .(hour, string)]
df1[, mode := string[which.max(n)], by=hour]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this - it works well and gives me what I'm looking for!  Very much appreciated.  I realized when I saw both of these answers just how out my league this maneuver was so much gratitude to both who answered!

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use the `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/how-to-find-the-statistical-mode)

```
 Mode <- function(x) {
       ux <- unique(x)
     ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Create a grouping variable by `paste`ing the 'date', 'time' columns, convert it to Datetime class with `dmy_hms` (from `lubridate`), then use `ceiling_date` specifying '1 hour' as `unit`, create the 'mode' column by applying the `Mode` on the 'string' column, and use `case_when` to return that value only at the last row for each group

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(grp = ceiling_date(dmy_hms(str_c(date, time, sep=" ")),
          '1 hour')) %>% 
     mutate(mode = case_when(row_number() == n() ~ Mode(string), 
                TRUE  ~ "")) %>%
     ungroup %>% 
     select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
#   date       time     string mode 
#   <chr>      <chr>    <chr>  <chr>
# 1 01/01/2020 20:04:01 A      ""   
# 2 01/01/2020 20:13:12 B      ""   
# 3 01/01/2020 20:37:45 C      ""   
# 4 01/01/2020 20:39:07 D      ""   
# 5 01/01/2020 20:41:29 A      ""   
# 6 01/01/2020 20:46:48 E      ""   
# 7 01/01/2020 21:00:00 J      "A"  
# 8 01/01/2020 21:20:12 I      ""   
# 9 01/01/2020 21:38:32 I      ""   
#10 01/01/2020 21:43:12 A      ""   
#11 01/01/2020 21:49:50 I      ""   
#12 01/01/2020 21:54:50 B      ""   
#13 01/01/2020 22:00:00 A      "I"  
#14 01/01/2020 22:03:45 B      "B"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("01/01/2020", "01/01/2020", "01/01/2020", 
"01/01/2020", "01/01/2020", "01/01/2020", "01/01/2020", "01/01/2020", 
"01/01/2020", "01/01/2020", "01/01/2020", "01/01/2020", "01/01/2020", 
"01/01/2020"), time = c("20:04:01", "20:13:12", "20:37:45", "20:39:07", 
"20:41:29", "20:46:48", "21:00:00", "21:20:12", "21:38:32", "21:43:12", 
"21:49:50", "21:54:50", "22:00:00", "22:03:45"), string = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "A", "E", "J", "I", "I", "A", "I", "B", "A", "B"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the wizardry on this one!  I really liked your solution and it executes given the data, but I was unable to get it to work on my df.  The other solution did so (due to time constraints) I'm going to implement that one.  I think perhaps my df is somehow structured a little differently than the input you're using - although I can't find the difference.  Your time is very, very much appreciated!